# Cant drop table because of a foreign key, but also cant drop foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to drop 2 tables -

1. `drop table employee;`
   that has one fk to itself - named 'super_id', and one to 'branch' table - named 'branch_id'
2. `drop table branch;`
   that has one fk to 'employee' table - 'mgr_id'

because they have referenced foreign keys between them, I get the error massage:
Cannot drop table 'employee' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'branch_ibfk_1' on table 'branch'/// and visa versa

so I tried dropping the constraints of the foreign keys between the two tables:
`ALTER TABLE employee DROP FOREIGN KEY super_id;  ALTER TABLE employee DROP FOREIGN KEY branch_id; ALTER TABLE branch DROP FOREIGN KEY mgr_id;`

but I also got an error, for the employee table:
"Can't DROP 'super_id' / 'branch_id'; check that column/key exists"

and for the branch table:
"Can't DROP 'mgr_id'; check that column/key exists"

I know I can erase the DB, but I want to know how to work correctly. can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?
TNX

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables.

Comment: You have to drop the FK name not the column that is being FK'd. please add table defintions as text to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on both tables

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DROP TABLE employees; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DROP TABLE branches; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Ahh the brute force approach..saves a lot of messing about..

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol;
```

`fk_symbol` = If the FOREIGN KEY clause defined a CONSTRAINT name when you created the constraint, you can refer to that name to drop the foreign key constraint
looks something like this = `employee_ibfk_1` on table `employee`

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee DROP FOREIGN KEY employee_ibfk_1;
```